# Fill the board with dominoes

Tags: recreational-mathematics, puzzle, tiling

Imagine a 8x8 cell board that is missing two cells at the opposite corners, a domino takes up exactly two cells. How can you fill the board with dominoes so that none overlap or hang off the edge?

[image]

Comment: Color it as a chessboard and count the number of white and black squares to see that it is impossible.

Comment: Before you ask "How can you fill the chessboard?" you should ask "Can you fill the chessboard?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a well-known problem - it even has its own wikipedia article: [Mutilated chessboard problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutilated_chessboard_problem).

[Here](http://www.math.washington.edu/~challenge/archive/20080812/threebyone.pdf) you can find a few similar but more challenging problems for [trominos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tromino).

Problems like this are usually solved using some type of coloring argument, as explained in Theo's comment and the above links.