# Probability of a number being rational

Tags: probability, integration, elementary-set-theory, rational-numbers

> If $x \in [0, 1]$, what is $\text{P}(x\in \mathbb Q)$? 
>   In other words, what is the probability that $x$ is rational?

This is what I tried:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}\text{P}(x \in \mathbb Q) &=& \displaystyle \int^1_0 f(x)\,dx
\end{array}$$

where

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}1, & x \in \mathbb Q\\0, & x\notin\mathbb Q\end{cases}$$

However, the function is not Riemann-integrable.

I want to try comparing the cardinalities of the rational set and the irrational set by using a one-to-one mapping between the two sets. But I don't have idea how I can do it. Can anyone give a hint?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer might miss the real goal, but is inspired by the tag "probability".

---

In your question it is not explicitly mentioned how probability $P$ is defined.

So actually the question: "what is the probability that $x$ is rational?" makes no sense in this context.

Your try indicates that you are thinking of *uniform distribution* on interval $[0,1]$ where: $$P(B):=\lambda(B\cap[0,1])$$ for every Borel set and $\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue measure on the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel sets $B\subseteq\mathbb R$.

It is well known that $\lambda(\{x\})=0$ for any $x\in\mathbb R$ and consequently we have $\lambda(S)=\sum_{x\in S}\lambda(\{x\})=0$ for every countable set, and of course $\mathbb Q$ is countable.

So under uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ we have $P(\mathbb Q)=0$.

In probability theory Riemann-integrability is (as far as I know) not practicized.

Notation $P(x\in \mathbb Q)$ only makes sense if $x$ denotes a *random variable* here.

So your problem setting: "if $x\in[0,1]$ then what is $P(x\in\mathbb Q)$?" is not okay.

Answer (score 16):

The function $f$ is indeed not Riemann-integrable, but it is Lebesgue-integrable. And its integral is $0$. Therefore, the answer is $0$. That is natural, since $\mathbb Q\cap[0,1]$ is countable, whereas $[0,1]$ is uncountable. It follows that there is no bijection between $\mathbb Q\cap[0,1]$ and $[0,1]\setminus\mathbb Q$.

Comment: What is the relation between a probability function and integration?

Comment: Probability theory is very much connected to measure theory. An we can compute the measure of a set by computing the integral of its characteristic function.

Comment: Thank you very much Dr. Santos. I'll inquire further on the subject. Can you recommend an article or book on the matter?

Comment: I think that [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1506416/probability-and-measure-theory) and its answers are a good starting point.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to try comparing the cardinalities of the rational set and the irrational set by using a one-to-one mapping between the two sets

You can't. The set of rationals is countable. The set of irrationals is uncountable (see [Proof that the irrational numbers are uncountable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/732/proof-that-the-irrational-numbers-are-uncountable)). Cantor proved by diagonalization that such that mapping cannot exist.